# how to compare a character to individual characters in a string?

Tags: java

I am trying to determine if the character at the beginning of a string is not equal to any of the characters in another string.

My problem is that even if the character is an 'a' for example it still trips on any of the other characters.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    public void searcher(String s)
    {
    boolean done = false;
    String checker = "_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (int x = 0; x < checker.length(); x++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(0) != checker.charAt(x))
        {
            System.out.println("Answer: " + s + "is not a valid identifier\n");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you heard about String.indexOf() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to print `System.out.println("Answer: " + s + "is not a valid identifier\n");` when `checker` does not contain the first character of `String s`. If so use this code to do it:

```
    public void searcher(String s)
    {
        String checker = "_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        if (checker.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Answer: " + s + " is not a valid identifier\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
boolean isValidIdentifier = checker.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) < 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) instead of `charAt`, like so:

```
if (checker.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) != -1) {
  // Valid identifier.
} else {
  // Invalid identifier.
}
```

In other words, check if your `checker` string contains (`indexOf != -1`) the first character of `s` (`s.charAt(0)`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your code as it is and modify a little bit, this is the change you need to do :

```
public void searcher(String s)  {

boolean isValid = false;
String checker = "_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (int x = 0; x < checker.length(); x++)
{
    if(s.charAt(0) == checker.charAt(x))
    {
        isValid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(isValid == true) //or if(isValid)
    System.out.println("Answer: " + s + "is a valid identifier\n");
else
    System.out.println("Answer: " + s + "is not a valid identifier\n");
}
```

Explanation:
what I did is :
By default suppose the first character of 's' is not valid, then iterate through the characters of the default string, if there is a match, then s is VALID and Break !

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

A few minor changes might help clarify things:

```
 public void searcher(String s)
 {
    String testValues = "_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    boolean found = false;
    char target = s.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i< testValues.length(); i++)
    {
        if(target == testValues.charAt(i))
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) 
      System.out.println ("target (" + target + "): FOUND");
    else
      System.out.println ("target (" + target + "): NOT FOUND");
 }
```

Equivalently, you can just lose the whole loop and use String.indexOf() instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a small regular expression matching method..
(code not tested ;)

also.. especially when new to coding, extract as much functionality as possible into neat small methods.

```
public void searcher(String s) {
  String checker = "_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  if (!matches(s.substring(0,1), checker))
    System.out.println("Answer: " + s + "is not a valid identifier\n");
}

public boolean matches(String test, String pattern) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("["+pattern+"]");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
  return m.matches();
}
```

Quick link to more info about regular expressions in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html